# Adobe Illustrator RGB Not showing anything

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi I need your help with my Adobe Illustrator 2021, when I open my RGB files there are no colors, objects appear also it's not on the outline mode but you can see the object under the layer tab an example image below:
[image]

but when I tried to switch it into CMYK Document Color Profile the colors appears:
[image]

Comment: Are there overlapping objects and other blending modest than normal? Have you some proof color view on in RGB mode, a printing plate that happens to be blank with your current object color? (Only a guess because you do not show essentials such as the layer panel as expanded and the appearance and the transparency panels)

Comment: I've never seen nor heard of this issue before. You may need to ask Adobe about this one.